# send the output of a file to a remote linux machine in one line

Tags: linux, command-line

How can I send the output of this file to home directory of another Linux machine.

Clearly, I want to send the output of this file:

```
sed '/^\s*#/d;/^$/d' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

To Home directory of this machine:

```
scp vagrant@192.168.33.10:httpd.conf
```

I want to consolidate these two command in only one command.

I am not sure if I can use `-` in the command line to do this job.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi who gave me downvote. I'd like comments with downvotes. Please leave a comment.

Comment: This isn't my downvote, but there is no obligation to leave comments with downvotes - somebody thought that the question does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful and acted accordingly. Maybe they also thought it's suspiciously similar to your last question?

Answer (score 1):

Use pipe with ssh.
E.g.:

```
 sed '/^\s*#/d;/^$/d' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | ssh vagrant@192.168.33.10 'cat > httpd.conf'
```